# How to get screen shot of webpage using javascript or jquery?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jakarta-ee

Likes to add screen shot submission for any bugs in my web application which developed using J2EE.That is if there is any bugs then client has the ability to take the screen shot of bug and submit for bug maintains.

So want a efficient mechanism to capture screen shot using JavaScript or Jquery since i want the screen shot of client using my web application.

Already tried with html2canvas.js but it doesn't work in IE8.Wants efficient solution that supports in IE8.

So please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: This blog should help: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2013/08/take-webpage-screenshot-html5-jquery-javascript.html

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966826/save-and-render-a-webpage-with-phantomjs-and-node-js

Comment: @shreyanshjogi I know its a duplicate question but didn't find any ideal solution ....appreciate your observation....Regrads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`excanvas.js` can be used in html to support canvas.Even though you can't solve it for html2canvas in IE8.