# evaluating only javascript elements within a page using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

I want to evaluate the javascript links on this website:

http://www.egypt.gov.eg

For example, I have this element:

```
<li class="language">
                        <a id="ctl00_btnLang" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$btnLang','')">English </a>
                        <img src="/CSS/images/langArwEn.gif" alt="Language Arrow" /></li>
```

So, I tried to use phantomjs to evaluate it, using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966826/save-and-render-a-webpage-with-phantomjs-and-node-js):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();  
var fs = require('fs'),
    system = require('system');

page.open('http://www.egypt.gov.eg', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var p = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementsByID('html')[0].innerHTML
        });
        fs.write('out.htm', p, 'w');
        console.log(p);
    }

    phantom.exit();
});
```

but it does not evaluate the html, it just returns it as is. So is there a way to evaluate the whole page html using phantomjs, and is there a way to single out elements which have javascript to be evaluated one by one?

Comment: I don't quite understand your purpose. Do you mean automatically execute `__doPostBack` then grab the page?

Comment: yes, that's what I basically need

Comment: and in general, if I find a piece of javascript in href, how can process it to retrieve the page which it is pointing to?

Comment: Just call the script directly in page.evaluate. If you only need to grab English version of the site, you can just visit this url instead: http://www.egypt.gov.eg/english/home.aspx

Comment: Look into `phantomjs cross-domain request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question is what do you mean by 'evaluate' the javascript links on the page... do you want PhantomJS to click on them?

Docs for page automation are here:
http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html

To click on this specific link you could do:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();  

page.open('http://www.egypt.gov.eg', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var p = page.evaluate(function () {
            document.getElementById('ctl00_btnLang').click()
        });
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

...but this is going to send the browser to a new url and I'm not sure what happens to your PhantomJS page object in that case.

Do you want to click all the javascript links on that page and grab the contents of each new HTML page that is loaded?

It seems like that would be easier with CasperJS *"CasperJS is a navigation scripting & testing utility for PhantomJS"*
http://docs.casperjs.org/

Have a look at the example code here which scrapes and follows links from an array of starting urls:
https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/samples/dynamic.js